# Cannot import rpy2.robjects from conda environment in Jupyter notebook but in console

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, conda, rpy2, jupyter-kernel

Importing rpy2.robjects fails in the jupyter notebook with `LookupError: 'show' not found`, however, import works in the commandline python interpreter with activated environment. How can I make it work in the notebook?

I have created the conda environment with rpy2 and ipykernel installed and have linked it to jupyter via `python -m ipykernel install --user --name env --display-name "env"` (within the activated environment). I looked up the path of the environment in kernel.json under the path provided by `jupyter kernelspec list` and found it to be the correct one of my environment. I do not get the error when I start jupyter notebook from within the activated environment and try to import rpy2.rojects. I would have thought that this should not make any difference. Furthermore, when starting the python interpreter via `./python` within the `~home/user/anaconda3/envs/env`, I do obtain the error. It seems some environment variables are set differently when starting the notebook with or without activated environment, but I do not have any clue which and how. I'll be happy about any hints to understand the issue.

Answer (score 0):

It does make a difference whether an environment is activated. You've already pointed out one solution, start Jupyter in the activated environment, and the kernels will inherit the corresponding environment variables.

Anaconda also has a kernel provider that finds kernels in all conda environments and automatically activates the environment when the kernel starts.

Another way is that you write your own kernelspec that calls a script. In that script, you can activate the conda environment before starting the kernel.